# JAVA Inheritance + Postgresql with json type

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I have an inheritance in JAVA, and our DBA suggested me to create one single table for all the children (like one single table strategy) but creating a json datatype with all the specific information. 
Is this a good practice?

I'll give an example, Having this three tables:

**Image**: thumbnailId long,
**Video**: duration int,
**Media**: id, name, description, type

Move to only one table:
**Media**: id, name, description, type, extra_fields

Where extra fields in the case of an image it should store thumbnail, an in the case of a video it should store duration as a json.

So:

1- Is this a good idea?

2- Is this easy to implement in JAVA+Spring?

Thanks

Comment: I would say that its never a good idea to store set of properties as a `json` in a `SQL` database. You'd loose both the Sql' Server's ability to query on those properties and and its capability to retrieve them quickly . A table per class/ concrete class is better, depending on the volume of data.

Comment: @anchreg what do you mean by depending on the volume of data? I think it's estimated to have between one and two thousand rows approximately... Concrete class will be better for my  case?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy to implement. Here is a sample :

```
@Entity(name = "Step")
@Table(name = "step")
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class StepEntity {

    @Column(name = "STEP_data")
    @Convert(converter = StepDataAttributeConverter.class)
    private StepData data;

    public StepEntity() {
        super();
    }

    @Data
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    public static class StepData {

        /* some fields */

        @JsonCreator
        public StepData() {
            super();
        }
    }
}

public class StepDataAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<StepEntity.StepData, String> {

    private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(StepEntity.StepData attribute) {

        if (attribute == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            try {
                return MAPPER.writeValueAsString(attribute);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public StepEntity.StepData convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        if (dbData == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            try {
                return MAPPER.readValue(dbData, StepEntity.StepData.class);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not really sure it's a good practice. It will be very hard to do search queries on this fields. In my case I had an elasticsearch to do all the searching. But if you haven't something similare, I suggest to think twice before doing this and really ensure that you haven't the need to do search on this fields.

Comment: And what fields whould you add inside StepData? All the fields?

Comment: Yes, and jackson handle inheritance. So if it is what you want, you can put image, video and media in a single column (keep care of the column size).

Comment: Note : My answer was in the case you want to serialize object as json string (varchar in database). I haven't experimented the Json Type of postgresql. I check the doc and it seams to exist ways to query json type. So I suppose that there isn't that much problem using it. But it may not be portable to other databases.

Comment: And with further reading, it appears that postgresql implements inverted indexes : https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/jsonb-type-performance-postgresql-9-4/